# Timeout on SQL Server creating table with name EXP_REG

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have problem creating a table with specific name, and only this name `EXP_REG`,

```
CREATE TABLE EXP_REG (CODE CHAR(2))
```

I get this error:

> Msg 121, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server.
>
> (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)

If I change name to `EXP_RE` it is created correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE EXP_RE (CODE CHAR(2))
```

But `EXP_REGANOTHER` has the same problem.

```
CREATE TABLE EXP_REGANOTHER (CODE CHAR(2))
```

and this not work either

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'EXP_REG')
```

Version of SQL Server in use:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
```

I don't understand this problem. This behavior does not happen in all versions

Comment: Could you look for OS level events? There could be networking issues

Comment: `The semaphore timeout period has expired` is a TCP-level networking error. Sounds like you have local network problems but it's very suspicious that it only happens for queries containing `EXP_REG`. Do you have some kind of so-called "Network Security" appliance that could be interfering with connections?

Comment: @SteveC On the same connection I can run different commands without problems like these.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Not sure. But in a sequence of commands, only this one is wrong